# Meaning of ことする in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> 「うるせえっ。わけのわからねぇ**ことする**奴なんて、一発や二発ぶんなぐってやりゃいいんだっ」
>   Shut up! It's alright to give one or two blows to the kind of idiots who **decide** not to understand the reason.

I'm unsure about the ことする part of this sentence. Is is just ことにする meaning "decide to ..." with the に dropped, or is there some other meaning?

Comment: Where did the translation came from?  Is it the official one?  (Which I doubt...)

Comment: That's my attempt. Is it **so** badly wrong?

Comment: Not so bad, but apparent that the gramatical interpretation is not correct.

Comment: FWIW, wake no wakaranai ~ incomprehensible. See ALC (Eijirou): http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E8%A8%B3%E3%81%8C%E5%88%86%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ことをする. を is omitted. And I think you left out a letter ら and わけのわからねぇことする奴 means "A guy who do nonsense".

Comment: Similar expression: ことがない.   =>   ことない.